# how to implement jquery Power Zoom with fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

how to implement jquery Power Zoom ( http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/powerzoomer.htm ) with fancybox ( http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/ ) ? 
I've tried this way, but still can not work

```
jQuery("#" + prefixId + "gallery a").fancybox({
    transitionIn: 'none',
    transitionOut: 'none',
    width: contentHeight,
    height: contentHeight,
    cyclic: true,
    onStart: function() {
        jQuery("#" + prefixId + "gallery").trigger("pause");
        jQuery("img.fancybox-image").addpowerzoom();
        console.log('start');
    },
    onClosed: function() {
        jQuery("#" + prefixId + "gallery").trigger("play");
        console.log('closed');
    },
    callbackOnShow: function() {
        jQuery("img.fancybox-image").addpowerzoom();
        console.log('show');
    },
    onComplete: function() {
        jQuery("img.fancybox-image").addpowerzoom();
        console.log('complete');
    }
});​
```

Comment: it seems that the fancybox API options (callbacks) you are using are not valid. Check the [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) for the proper callbacks (hint: bind powerzomm using the `beforeShow` callback)

Comment: another hint: `cyclic` was replaced by `loop`